# Why it shows unknown substitution command?

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to use a launch file. But it shows unknown substitution command. I don't know why.

```
<launch>
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="map_file" default="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/maps/map.yaml"/>
    <arg name="open_rviz" default="true"/>


    <!-- Run the map server -->
    <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(turtlbot3_navigation)/map/map.yaml" >
        <param name="frame_id" value="/map" />
    </node>

    <group ns="robot1">
        <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot1_tf" />
        <param name="amcl/initial_pose_x" value="1" />
        <param name="amcl/initial_pose_y" value="1" />
        <include file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/new_move_base.launch" />
    </group>

    <group ns="robot2">
        <param name="tf_prefix" value="robot2_tf" />
        <param name="amcl/initial_pose_x" value="-1" />
        <param name="amcl/initial_pose_y" value="1" />
        <include file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/new_move_base.launch" />
    </group>

    <!--node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find your_pkg)/config/multi.vcg"
          output="screen" -->
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" required="true"
          args="-d $(find turtlebot3_navigation)/rviz/turtlebot3_navigation.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

The terminal shows:

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation multiple_navigation.launch 
... logging to /home/ise-admin/.ros/log/406b2672-a176-11e8-841a-509a4c311940/roslaunch-ise-linux-1-6017.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Unknown substitution command [turtlbot3_navigation]. Valid commands are ['find', 'env', 'optenv', 'anon', 'arg']
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I can't find the log file in /.ros/log. Do you know why it shows Unknown substitution command?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300754/why-it-shows-unknown-substitution-command?/) by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2018-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(turtlbot3_navigation)/map/map.yaml" >
> ```

This seems to be missing a `find` right before `turtlbot3_navigation` in the `args` attribute.

`turtlbot3_navigation` is not a valid `roslaunch` substitution command, so the error would seem to be correct.

It should probably be:

```
args="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/map/map.yaml"
```

(note I also corrected the typo there (missing `e` between `l` and `b`)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2018-08-16**:
Thank you very much!!!  I didn't find it even with the compiler. It is amazing that you find out it directly. Thank you again!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-17**:\

> compiler

which compiler?

A launch file is not compiled, so building your workspace wouldn't help.

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2018-08-17**:
You are right. I use clion. At least, a compiler helps to find out the key words and have a better arrangement of each line.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-17**:
Ah, you mean an IDE?